# Calculate Revenue based on Date Range

Tags: app-development

I have a Custom Object that has a start date and an end date. I want to run a report that will  calculate revenue based on the overlap between the report filter time period and the date range.  For example, 
if 
start_date = 1/1/2013, end_date = 4/30/2013, hourly rate is $100
and report filter = 4/1/2013 to 6/30/2013

the summary for the report should = (Number_of_Hours from 4/1/2013 to 4/30/2013) * 100

I know this can be done if I have a Master-Detail object structure, with the monthly info stored in the 'Detail' object.... but this is just a simple calculation, and I wanted to see if there's a way to calculate the date overlap between the object's date range and the report filter date range.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with standard Salesforce Reports? If so, you would need to use the report filter criteria within a report formula, which I don't think is possible.

Comment: I think you've already hit on the answer: Design the data model to support the desired reports. Are there any constraints preventing you from implementing a Master-Detail structure?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar request form a customer, how wanted to enter the start and end date on the fly. we ended up creating a custom VF page for this, as SFDC reports do not support dynamic variables ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can easily be done using a report (because you want to access the report's "From Date" and "To Date" in a formula).  The following yields your result:

> Create a few fields in your custom object: a FromDate, ToDate, and
>   HourlyRate.  Then create a formula to calculate the number of hours
>   between the two dates and multiply that result by the HourlyRate. 
>   (The difference in dates give the number of days between them, and
>   then multiply by 24 for the number of hours per day, then multiply by
>   the hourly rate.)
>
> ```
> (ToDate__c - FromDate__c)*(24)*HourlyRate__c
> ```

**---Edit---**

If you need this as a column in a report for all records in your report (not calculated individually like above), use a Summary report and then create a formula.  I am pretty sure you'll have to calculate the number of days between your dates "manually"

```
numDaysBetween*(24)*100
```

Comment: Thanks amatorVitae, unfortunately that still shows the same number regardless of the report period. For example, if the start date is 6/21/2012, end date is 6/21/2013, I get the same total whether I view a single quarter, current year or previous year.

Comment: It won't show in the report per se.  The idea is to go to a record, input the dates & rate, and the formula will populate the desired value.  Are you trying to show this as a column on a report with the same value for each record?

Comment: yes, kind of.  So, if the value for the year is $120,000... ideally I wanted to find a way to show a value of $10,000 on a Monthly report.